# gcc optimization flags in O2 that causes undefined symbol

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc

I have a problem with -O2 in gcc 4.5.2. Say I have this code:

```
//file.cpp
void test::f() {}
//file.h
struct test
{
    inline void f();
};
```

This code is in the shared library. Now, when I compile without -O2, it works fine. With -O2 it says that test::f() is undefined symbol. Obviously gcc just throws it away because it's "inline" (though it is really not).

My question is what specific optimization flag causes this? The idea is that I want to enable -O2 but disable that exact flag so that I can keep inlines untouched (that's not my code).

I can probably just iterate all of them but, this can also be linker flag, right? This is too much work, I just hope someone will have a clue.

Answer (score 6):

The standard requires that the definition of an `inline` function is present in every TU that uses it.

Either remove `inline` or else move the definition of the function to the header file. Even if what you want to do were allowed, there would be no benefit in marking the function `inline`.

It just so happens that on your implementation you have a problem with `-O2` but apparently no problem without it.

Comment: I will check if inline in both .h/.cpp will help with -O2. As for removing inline or moving code to the header, I can't do this.

Comment: No, inline in .cpp did not help.

Comment: @queen3: Why did you think that using inline in the .cpp would make any difference? doing this isn't consistent with either of SteveJessop's solutions.

Comment: @queen3: I didn't say *add* `inline` to `f` in the cpp file, I said *remove* it from `f` in the header file. If you can't remove inline from the header or move the definition then as a work-around you could copy and paste the definition of `f` from `file.cpp` into every source file that calls `f` (or into a new header that they all include). Watch out though, because now you have duplicated code and if it gets out of sync you get undefined behavior. The reason you have duplicated code is your inability to modify `file.h`, so that should be addressed.

Comment: No it is not preventing _me_ from writing correct C++ because I do not write it. I just have to deal with it.

Comment: @queen3: the program that uses `file.h` and links against `file.cpp` is incorrect, and you wrote that program ;-p. It will still be incorrect, even if you can find an optimization level at which it appears to work on your implementation. Possibly you should ditch `file.h` and write your own header file for the component, and fix the author's errors that way.

Comment: Or slightly unorthodox, but if *all* the functions in `file.cpp` are inline (and it contains no objects with external linkage) then you could `#include "file.cpp"` in your TU. With a guard against multiple inclusion. All of which is different ways of achieving the same thing, which is to get the definition of `f` into your TU where it belongs.

Comment: No, I did not wrote that program (nor the libraries).

Comment: @queen3: then maybe you should ask the person who did write it how they compiled it, what compiler options they think it supports, and why they're giving you broken code. If you're not programming, then technically the question is off topic for SO, but personally I think it's OK anyway ;-)

Comment: Yes I did. They said to find a fix without touching inlines. They give me the broken code because it works for them for 10 years (for the other platform), they see no reason to change it in all 100 modules just because gcc (which is not their platform) can't cope with it.

Comment: @queen3: then you have my sympathies: they suck and they can't be bothered to stop sucking. If you can't have a negotiation with them how to make their code pay attention to the C++ standard, then you may well have a lot of problems like this until eventually you hit one that you can't fix without modifying their code.

Comment: I see that you know what I am talking about ;-)

Comment: @queen3: Create a parallel header with the inlined functions defined in the header and use it. Also note that refactoring the definition of the function into the header will **not** cause any issue if the function is really marked inline. The last option would be reaching to your manager, point the bug in the implementation and point that without the other group fixing the issues the code is broken and cannot be used with other compilers/flags.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to fix or reject the broken code. Inline functions must be defined in any translation unit that uses them, and this code breaks that rule.

If that isn't an option, then `-fkeep-inline-functions` might patch over the problem well enough to allow the code to compile and link.

Comment: No, -fkeep-inline-functions took 30 minutes for ld and ate 16GB of memory (that's because the project is huge and has a LOT of inline functions - making them all go into shared library is a bad idea).

Comment: @queen3: Then it sounds like you have no option but to fix the broken code. Sorry.

Comment: I can #define inline and have gcc to decide what to inline. But that feels like a hack, I'd prefer to do a specific optimization flag or something like that.

Comment: @queen3: Indeed, some functions (those defined in a header and outside a class definition) *must* be declared inline, so removing all uses of `inline` would break the code in other ways. If you want to play with optimisation flags, then the optimisations enabled at each level are given [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). However, be warned that my compiler (4.6.3) rejects your code at all optimisation levels, so whatever bodge you find may well break if you upgrade the compiler.

Comment: Valid inlines can probably still work in .h if I #define inline __attribute__((weak)). I think eventually I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

You can force `gcc` to ignore `inline` using the flag `-fno-inline`.

Comment: That pretty much conflicts with the idea of using -O2.

Comment: @queen3 - no, it conflicts with marking something `inline` when it isn't.